# [-f: command not found

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to write a program in bash shell which handles a file. I have to call my program from the command line with various ways so they can print specific columns each time. Let's give for example this call:

```
./prog.sh -f file
```

my code for this part is

```
if [[( $1 == '-f') && ( $2 == '<file>')]] ; then 
 echo "do stuff and print column"
```

I do get the column I want printed, however I'm also getting the following warning:

> [-f command was not found

Any idea on how to remove the error?

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: I can't reproduce that error message with that code (on GNU Bash 4.3). Are you sure that that's the part of your code that's causing the error?

Comment: The specific line you gave doesn't cause the error, *but* despite the lack of a working [mcve], it's an error with a very-well-understood cause, for which we have numerous duplicative, already-answered questions.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there's space around the square brackets. `[[` and `]]` need to be separate tokens. The parentheses don't add anything and can be deleted. (If you leave them they also need spaces on both sides.)

```
if [[ $1 == '-f' && $2 == '<file>' ]]; then 
    echo "do stuff and print column"
fi
```

For what it's worth, the `$2` check probably shouldn't be there. Any string is a valid file name.

Answer (score -2):

You should rewrite the file check as a test so your code would be:

```
if [[( -f $1 ) && ( $2 == '<file>')]] ; then 
   echo "do stuff and print column"
```

Comment: i don't think that's what the OP meant - the `-f` is there as a flag argument

Comment: @EliranMalka yes you're right, didn't see that.